# What does ‘of’ mean here? 'Cambridge is the main city and administrative centre of Cambridgeshire.'

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Cambridge is the main city and administrative centre **of** Cambridgeshire.

In Oxford Advanced Learner’s Dictionary, I think the appropriate definition may be:

2. belonging to something; being part of something: relating to something
   example (1): a member of the team
3. used to say what somebody/something is, consists of, or contains
   example (2): a city of Dublin

I think the appropriate definition for that sentence should be 2, but example (2) make me feel uncertain.

Comment: Even the Oxford dictionary couldn't list all the possible meanings of "of".   With these kind of small prepositions, I would rely more on understanding how they're *used* rather than how the dictionary *defines* them.   In this particular sentence the relationship between Cambridge and Cambridgeshire should be obvious.

Comment: @Andrew is correct. In this case, rather than the example "member of the team" one should think "captain of the team" or "coach of the team." That is, Cambridge fills a role with regard to Cambridgeshire. It is a relationship indicator along the lines of "the A of B."

Answer (score 1):

I believe 2. would be correct because the city of Cambridge does not consist of or contain Cambridgeshire. Cambridge is a part of Cambridgeshire.